# MySQL/MariaDB configuration sections for client

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

Is there a way, how can I print default configuration variables or  configuration sections for mysql/mariadb client?

I have a configuration file for example:

```
    [client]
    user = abc
    passw = bcd
    !include /another/my.cnf
    !includedir /another/configurations/
```

In /another/my.cnf I have

```
    [clientA]
    user = abc
    passw = bcd
    host = example.com
```

I would like to know wheter the configuration section [clientA] exists.

Now when I connect to `mysql --defaults-group-suffix=B` it still connects me based on the [client] section without any warning, that suffix B is nonexistent.

Is there any command that should print me the combined my.cnf file with it's sections?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [my_print_defaults](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/my_print_defaults/) utility. Use of --defaults-group-suffix makes the utility read options from groups with the specified suffix **alongwith** the usual groups.